# How can I save a photo taken with UIImagePickerController camera to be displayed later in the app?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, camera

I am having the user take a photo with UIImagePickerController and I need it to be saved to the app so that it can be displayed when they need to see it later. How can I accomplish this?

I have heard NSUserDefaults would be a mistake. All I need to save is a single image, never more.

Comment: Save that image to your document folder.Whenever you want that image retrieve that image from that document folder.

Comment: Do you have an example of code to do this? I've never run into this before.

Comment: i have posted the code, hope that helps you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is the function to save your image to document folder

```
func saveImage (image: UIImage, path: String ) -> Bool{
        let pngImageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)
         //let jpgImageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0)   // if you want to save as JPEG
        let result = pngImageData.writeToFile(path, atomically: true)
        return result
    }
```

Here is the function to get your document directory path with image name

```
func fileInDocumentsDirectory(filename: String) -> String {
    let documentsFolderPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true)[0] as! String
    return documentsFolderPath.stringByAppendingPathComponent(filename)
}
```

Here is an example of how to use your image path

```
let imagePath = fileInDocumentsDirectory(myImageName)
```

And here is how you save your image to that folder

```
saveImage(image, path: imagePath)
```

Now the last part is to get your image, so use this function to get your image

```
func loadImageFromPath(path: String) -> UIImage? {
    let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: path)
    if image == nil {
        println("Image not available at: (path)")
    }
    return image
}
```

And here is how you use the above function

```
image = loadImageFromPath(imagePath)
imageView.image = image
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: I just wanted to verify for anyone using this page as reference that this solution works. Just remember to replace the placeholders throughout the above code with what you're using in your own code.