# Load image form Gallery in swift from path given by UIImagePickerViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

I am saving path in Database return by UIImagepicker from Gallery

```
 let imageURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] as! NSURL
            let imageName = imageURL.lastPathComponent
            let documentDirectory = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true).first! as String

            //let localPath = documentDirectory.stringByAppendingPathComponent(imageName!)

            let imagePath = String("\(documentDirectory)/\(imageName!)")
```

where path look like

> /Users/kshitijghule/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/3AC7B500-E980-4A00-BC32-34FA3C7DDE8A/data/Containers/Data/Application/838FB5A1-4448-46C9-8BEC-2E939668B97D/Documents/asset.JPG

Now i want load this image from this path.

```
i used this code 


   let url = NSURL(string:"/Users/kshitijghule/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/3AC7B500-E980-4A00-BC32-34FA3C7DDE8A/data/Containers/Data/Application/838FB5A1-4448-46C9-8BEC-2E939668B97D/Documents/asset.JPG")!//path from database but mention static 
     let imageData = NSData(contentsOfURL:url)!   
   cell?.petImageView.image = UIImage(data: imageData)
```

But i am getting crash at line

```
let imageData = NSData(contentsOfURL:url)!
```

How to fix this issue? It will work on device ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save image in Document Directory taken from Gallery or Camera.

```
 func origionalImage(origionalImage: UIImage!, editedImage: UIImage!, userInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject]!) {

            let imageData = NSData(data:UIImagePNGRepresentation(origionalImage)!)
            let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true)
            let docs: String = paths[0]

            let imageName = self.randomStringWithLength(6) as String
            //imageName can save in sqlite to load image later
            let fullPath = String("\(docs)/\(imageName).png")
             print(fullPath)
            let result = imageData.writeToFile(fullPath, atomically: true)
            print("FILE WRITTEN SUCCESS=>:\(result)")
}
```

Load Image from Database

```
        let tempDBObject = self.petListArray[indexPath.row] as! Database
        cell?.petName.text = tempDBObject.Hname
        //Doc Path
        let documentDirectory = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true).first! as String
        let imagePath = String("\(documentDirectory)/\(tempDBObject.Hpath!)")
        if imagePath == "" {
        }else{
           cell?.petImageView.image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imagePath)
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are storing images in the document directory store only image name in the db

At the time of retrieval append the current document directory path with your image name like you done at save time

```
let documentDirectory = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true).first! as String

//let localPath = documentDirectory.stringByAppendingPathComponent(imageName!)
//imageName which you have stored in the db at retrieval time
let imagePath = String("\(documentDirectory)/\(imageName!)")

let url = NSURL(string:imagePath)
let imageData = NSData(contentsOfURL:url)!
```

as i have also this type of issue at last if found that the app number of simulator(838FB5A1-4448-46C9-8BEC-2E939668B97D) is changes which cause the issue

Hope this may solve your issue

Comment: I used that path only at save time but still have crash.

Comment: @AvijitNagare which path you stored ? I am telling you to store only the image name not the full path, the above code is for retrieval, 
there may be error in converting the path to url, check if NSURL is properly created and then pass it to NSData and also check if at every run time the path is same(App folder number)  or it's changing

Answer (score 0):

I have answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32184619/how-can-i-save-a-photo-taken-with-uiimagepickercontroller-camera-to-be-displayed/32185592#32185592).You only have to save those paths to your database, and from the database path you can retrieve those images.

Comment: I want image from gallery. they are already save on device. do i really need to save in document directory?

Comment: The path which is shown in you code is not of asset gallery, its of Document Directory, `"/Users/kshitijghule/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/3AC7B500-E980-4A00-BC32-34FA3C7DDE8A/data/Containers/Data/Application/838FB5A1-4448-46C9-8BEC-2E939668B97D/Documents/asset.JPG`

Comment: you are correct so can i get asset gallery path? or i need to save image in document directory?

Comment: Its upto you, how you want to implement it, suppose if the image is deleted from the Photos App and still you want to use that image in app, then you have to save them in document directory, or else if you dont want to increase the size of your app in document directory then you can use Asset url.

Comment: Thanks bro. Could you past code to get Asset url path ? how to get that?

Comment: you are getting the asset path in your code `let imageURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] as! NSURL` you have to use this path, then search about how to get image from asset path.

Comment: saving UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL gives crash as in question